# Remove emoji button in android kitkat keyboard

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, emoji

Hi I need to disable the emoji button in android KitKat keyboard in my android application. Can anybody know how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Standard kitkat keyboard doesn't have any emoji buttons. It could be a part of the particular app, non-standard keyboard or modified system.

Comment: Seems otherwise. It's coming by default on some of the devices like Note 3 and LG G3

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this is possible. I suggest this is set up by the (individual) user's keyboard settings. Some keyboards doesn't support emoji.

The only way I know to handle keyboard appearance is to set a EditText to numerical. This will pop off a numerical keyboard layout.

But I'm not sure at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `<EditText android:inputType="textShortMessage">` try replacing it by `<EditText android:inputType="textLongMessage">`

However I don't think you can control what keyboard the user is using for input, so you could still get emoji characters.